# Javascript datepicker input field not firing

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have the following code which seems to work okay. It uses the datepicker and when two dates are added the totaldays field is populated by the amount of days between the two dates:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#dateone" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    minDate: 0,
    firstDay: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1));
        $( "#datetwo" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", newMin );
      var d1 = $('#dateone').datepicker('getDate');
      var d2 = $('#datetwo').datepicker('getDate');
      var diff = 0;
      if (d1 && d2) {
            diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
      }
      $('#totaldays').val(diff);



    }
});
$( "#datetwo" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    minDate: '+2d',
    changeMonth: true,
    firstDay: 0,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var newMax  = new Date(maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1));
        $( "#dateone" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate",  newMax);
      var d1 = $('#dateone').datepicker('getDate');
      var d2 = $('#datetwo').datepicker('getDate');
      var diff = 0;
      if (d1 && d2) {
            diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
      }
      $('#totaldays').val(diff);

    }
});

$("#dateone").datepicker('setDate', '+1');
$("#datetwo").datepicker('setDate', '+2');


</script>
```

Whilst the totaldays is updated, the change event doesn't seem to be firing. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What change event? You're saying that `totaldays` is updating, and that's *inside* the change event, so surely that's firing - no?

Comment: Sorry, I have other fields: 

- color dropdown
- parcels dropdown
- A price field

The total price = color * parcels * totaldays

When I change the dates the price doesn't update, however it updates when I change the totaldays field manually.

I guessed it was because the datepicker isn't firing correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) on the `totaldays` input to trigger the change event.

e.g.

```
$('#totaldays').val(diff).change();
```

Example code:

```js
$("#dateone").datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  minDate: 0,
  firstDay: 0,
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1));
    $("#datetwo").datepicker("option", "minDate", newMin);
    var d1 = $('#dateone').datepicker('getDate');
    var d2 = $('#datetwo').datepicker('getDate');
    var diff = 0;
    if (d1 && d2) {
      diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
    }
    $('#totaldays').val(diff).change();
  }
});

$("#datetwo").datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  minDate: '+2d',
  changeMonth: true,
  firstDay: 0,
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var newMax = new Date(maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - 1));
    $("#dateone").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newMax);
    var d1 = $('#dateone').datepicker('getDate');
    var d2 = $('#datetwo').datepicker('getDate');
    var diff = 0;
    if (d1 && d2) {
      diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
    }
    $('#totaldays').val(diff).change();
  }
});

$("#dateone").datepicker('setDate', '+1');
$("#datetwo").datepicker('setDate', '+2');

$("#totaldays,#color,#parcels").change(function() {
  var totaldays = parseInt($(this).val());
  var color = parseInt($("#color").val());
  var parcels = parseInt($("#parcels").val());
  $("#totalprice").val(totaldays * color * parcels);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="dateone" type="text" />
<input id="datetwo" type="text" />
<div>
  Total Days
  <input id="totaldays" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  Color
  <input id="color" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  Parcels
  <input id="parcels" type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  Total Price
  <input id="totalprice" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Thanks H77!

Comment: @pele09 please accept the answer if it worked for you.